# Know ruby gem system dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there is a way to know specific gem system libraries dependencies? like **pg** gem **postgresql** or **nokogiri** gem **libxslt-dev libxml2-dev**

Comment: Probably not in a generic way, e.g., the dependencies are specified differently in the two gems, and native dependencies are not shown through `gem dep -R`. Caveat: running a pretty old version of Rails and Bundler at the moment :/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, [the `natives` gem](https://github.com/teohm/natives) should probably do the trick. It can read a Gemfile, or find native dependencies for gems on your system, etc.

Caveat: I haven't tried it, because it doesn't appear to support Windows and I'm not at a Linux system at the moment.